# Bot is unable to process your request

Tags: google-hangouts

I have a GChat bot with some custom method, and I am unsure what the right "action response" is supposed to be.

I am using the default action response as seen in documentation: https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/bot-dialogs?hl=en

```
"action_response": {
                "type": "DIALOG",
                "dialog_action": {
                    "action_status": "OK"
                }
            }
```

Here is what the bot is returning despite a 200 status returned, after the timeout -

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhpVt.png]

Comment: Can you pl put what code is written on click of 'ACKNOWLEDGE'?

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi it is just some other code that updates a jira ticket status. What I am looking for is the right action_response so the card_clicked method does not time out.

Comment: In order to understand the exact issue, I will need to have all code snippets - based on this error it can be happening even in that JIRA ticket status update as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other message types, button clicks expects additional details to be sent in the response. It needs to respond with `NEW_MESSAGE` or `UPDATE_MESSAGE`.
Like this.

```
{
  "actionResponse":{
    "type":"UPDATE_MESSAGE"
  },
  "cards":[
    {
      "header":{
        "title":"Hello World!"
      },
      "sections": ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).